# How to fix 'SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Warning: Task "sass" not found' when loading gruntfile.js tasks?

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, syntax-error

I cant't start to scss to css compiling using grunt sass.

This is my gruntfile.js:

```
const sass = require('node-sass');

require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

grunt.initConfig({
   sass: {
      options: {
          implementation: sass,
          sourceMap: true
      },
      dist: {
          files: {
              'style.css':'style.scss'
          }
      }
   }

   grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass']);
 });`
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `registerTask()` inside `initConfig()`. It needs to be moved outside:

```
const sass = require('node-sass');

require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {
        options: {
            implementation: sass,
            sourceMap: true
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                'main.css': 'main.scss'
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass']);
```

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sass